# Backreference with sed

Tags: regex, sed, backreference

I am trying to rearrange headers in my fasta file. I thought I could select the first 10 characters, then the rest of the line, and then backreference the first selection to move it to the end.

> AY843768_1 Genus species 12S

would then be

> Genus species 12S AY843768_1

I need to use sed for a learning exercise, but I am unsure how to make the selections to switch the 10-digit ID to the end of the line for every header in my file.

```
sed ‘s/^\(.\{10\}\)(.*$)/\2 \1/g' file1.fasta > file2.fasta
```

Comment: Using gawk is easier: gawk 'BEGIN{FS=" "} {print $2, $3, $4,$1}'  file1.tasta.  Of cause, maybe you don't want to use gawk.

Comment: You need to use `-E` option, since `()` and `{}` are not metacharacters in default BRE mode

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
sed 's/^\(.\{10\}\) \(.*\)/\2 \1/' file1.fasta > file2.fasta
```

- backslashes at the second braces where missing.
- .* already matches the rest of the line so $ isn't needed
- g isnt needed cause multiple matches per line arent possible if expression begins with ^

Anyway, using ERE instead of BRE makes it more readable:

```
sed -E 's/^(.{10}) (.*)/\2 \1/' file1.fasta > file2.fasta
```

OT: Same (or similar) can be achieved with bash only:

```
while read id rest;do echo "$rest $id";done <file1.fasta >file2.fasta
```